# Encoding fails whatever I try

Tags: content-encoding

I am trying to set my site's encoding to UTF-8 but I fail. Environment: Ubuntu Desktop 13.04, Apache 2.2, PHP+FPM.
Added a .htacces:
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Meta:

file -bi * output:
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
text/html; charset=utf-8
inode/directory; charset=binary
inode/directory; charset=binary
text/x-php; charset=utf-8
inode/directory; charset=binary
text/x-php; charset=us-ascii
inode/directory; charset=binary
text/x-php; charset=us-ascii

(similar in subdirectories)

System encoding is also UTF-8.

PHP header:
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8");

The problem itself:
When I echo accent letters like this: echo "ÁÁÁ
\n"; it prints out them well. But when I send these letters through a post form, they become these: �

Maybe my browsers encoding messes up everything? I really hope no, because everything is on default. Anyway, w3c validator says it is a valid HTML5 UTF-8 encoded page.

A hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you storing this text in a database before it gets corrupted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I use MySQL (also UTF-8), these POST variables are not stored in database, so there is interaction with it. Anyway I am using gedit with UTF-8 encoding (I am not sure) it may happen it uses BOM. I tried to check it but I could not find anything. Now I am trying Kate.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://allseeing-i.com/How-to-setup-your-PHP-site-to-use-UTF8

> Unicode is not quite a first class citizen in PHP, so you'll have to do some tweaking to get it to grok UTF-8.
>
> Firstly, you need to ensure that you have MBString enabled in your copy of PHP. If you're on Linux and using a packaged PHP, it may be installed by default. If not, it's probably just a case of adding it with:
>
> `$ yum install php-mbstring`
>
> ...
>
> Assuming you have multi-byte support built-in, now you need to make sure PHP knows that you want to handle text as UTF-8 internally. Add the following to an include that gets parsed before anything else, and you should be good to go:
>
> ```
> //setup php for working with Unicode data
> mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
> mb_http_output('UTF-8');
> mb_http_input('UTF-8');
> mb_language('uni');
> mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
> ob_start('mb_output_handler');
> ```
>
> If you're doing anything with strings other than reading them from a database and outputing them, you'll probably want to read about PHP's multi-byte functions. Basically, many string functions have multi-byte capable alternatives, with the prefix 'mb_'. So, substr() becomes mb_substr()

Comment: This is a really good advice. Unfortunately it did not help either. Anyway I already have had mbstring enabled, but did not included the code above. Now I fixed it but this time it prints '?' instead of '?' in a black square. It does not mean anything for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what Kate did (or not) but I installed Notepad++ with wine. I checked the encoding of every files and it says they are UTF-8 without BOM. So there is no problem with the files I suppose. The other thing I realized is not the POST that messes up everything. However I still don't know what it is. The situation:

WORKING:
- echo "ÁÁÁÓŰŰÓÓŰ";
- $a="ÚÚŰŰÓÓÍ";"function p($s){echo $s;} p();

NOT WORKING:
- $a="ÚÚŰŰÓÓÍ";"function p($s){echo $s[0];} p();

Problem: it prints out question marks.

What the hell?